# iOS Safari is autofilling every field with the same thing?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, safari

I am constructing a simple form where a user can enter their name/email and their friend's name/email. Sample code is below.

In every browser apart from iOS Safari, the autofill function only completes the first 2 fields but my iPhone is completing fields 1 and 3 with my name, and fields 2 and 4 with my email.

If I remove the "name" attribute altogether, the issue still happens. If I then remove the text before the  field or spell name/email differently, the issue stops. It's as though iOS Safari is seeing a field that has "name" and thinks it's the same thing.

Is there any way around this? I just want it to only complete the first 2 fields, and using autocomplete="off" does nothing.

```
<div>My name: <input name="fullName" type="text"></div>
<div>My email: <input name="email" type="email"></div>
<div>Friend's name: <input name="friendFullName" type="text"></div>
<div>Friend's email: <input name="friendEmail" type="email"></div>
```

EDIT #1

I have just tried to replicate this issue with other websites that utilise a similar form design and the issue is occurring there for me too.

Open this in iOS Safari and try to autofill your name/email: http://www.rightmove.co.uk/sendPropertyToFriend/sendPropertyToFriend.html?propertyIds=63218243&from=%2Fproperty-for-sale%2Fproperty-63218243.html

If this sounds like a bug, I'll report to Apple and close this post. But Apple are so slow at fixing issues, so a workaround would be great if one exists.

EDIT #2

Chrome works as expected - it autofills the first two fields and only autofills the other two fields if you click/tap into any of those fields and choose the autofill option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I can reproduce this bug in Safari 10.1.2 for macOS and I've tested a few scenarios to see exactly when it occurs. Your findings are pretty much in line with mine - if the field has `name` or `email` in the text preceding it, and/or in its HTML `name=` attribute, Safari identifies it as autofillable.

So, while this two-prong soution is a bit hacky, it will definitely stop the fields from autofilling:

1. Obscure the `name=` attribute of these fields to remove those keywords. I've used `friendFn` instead of `friendFullName`, and `friendEm` instead of `friendEmail`.
2. Use the decorative `::before` CSS property to label these fields in a way that Safari doesn't detect when autofilling.

You can see these changes implemented in this snippet below. Hope this helps!

```css
[data-label]::before {
  content: attr(data-label) ': ';
}
```

```html
<div>My name: <input name="fullName" type="text"></div>
<div>My email: <input name="email" type="email"></div>
<div data-label="Friend's name"><input name="friendFn" type="text"></div>
<div data-label="Friend's email"><input name="friendEm" type="email"></div>
```

Comment: Also worth noting, if any field contains "name", such as "placeholder", it will autofill that field. Stupid Safari!